# Ldapsearch filtering using variables not displaying data

Tags: linux, bash, ldap

I am currently trying to query an LDAP server to find whether the email passed to the script exists on our system.

Below is the ldapsearch command I am trying to use:

```
ldapdata=`ldapsearch -h ### -b "ou=###,o=###" "email=$email" email firstname surname`
echo "ldapdata: $ldapdata"
```

This works perfectly when the filter includes a predetermined email, ie "mail=firstname-surname@###" however when passed a variable, such as $email, the output is not able to be manipulated by further grep / awk statements and will not display any data in the echo statement.

From some Googling I have figured out It could be to do with the line wrapping which LDAP uses.

What I have already tried to solve the issue:

```
| perl -p00e 's/\r?\n //g

| sed '/^$/d

-o ldif-wrap=no
```

My question is, what is the best method to solve this issue. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone having the same issue, the issue was actually due to me writing and testing the program in a Windows environment.

I was pulling the $email variable from a file that is in the dos format.

To fix this all I did was :

```
dos2unix $FILELOCATION
```